# Copy static cell value in Numbers

Tags: numbers

In numbers I have a table that contains some configuration values, I reference these in formulas but when I copy and paste the cells using the configuration values it breaks as it increments the cell position.

How can I copy and paste the cells but maintain the reference to the configuration value?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the $ char e.g. like this: `=$D$3`

Answer (score 0):

This works great. You can also simply use this statement: `=$cell,cell#`
This will copy the value of the Cell/cellNumber to the highlighted cell of interest. Changing the value in one, will automatically reflect the changes in the other cell.